# Algorithm to handle group seating arrangement

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

## The Problem

Say we have a theater with a capacity of 130 and we know exactly how many group sections we have allocated i.e - a few sections reserved for groups of 4, you have a few sections reserved for groups of 3, and so on. The only the only constraint is - two separate groups can not be seated together, so 2 groups of 2 cannot be seated in the section reserved for groups of 4, however if there are no other groups of 4, then a group of 3 can be seated in the section for groups of 4.

I know this is a variation of the bin covering or bin packing algorithms but I am struggling with coming up with the correct solution.

I hoping to use the algorithm in a python script to get some data sorted. if anyone is already familiar with something that can accomplish this, please steer me in the right direction

Comment: I coded something like this using Simulated Annealing [here](https://github.com/miquelvir/covid-seating-optimization).

Comment: What does that output? How are the constraints similar or different to the constraints we have - if you have some time, I'd love to connect with you and get this tweaked to work for my use case!

Comment: Well the thing is that I had no clue how to find a good algorithm if we had a complex set of constraints. In a sense, the output could only be as good as my algorithm; and every constraint change would be a nightmare, so I chose SA. The idea is that adding constraints to it is really easy (check [follows_covid_guidelines](https://github.com/miquelvir/covid-seating-optimization/blob/master/seatings.py), there you can basically given a seat see if it follows the guidelines. If I were you, I would take a look at the general structure and simulated_annealing.py, and then make it yours.

Comment: @miquelvir if my only constraints is: one can seat by people of the same social bubble, how would I remove the other two constraints you have in place?